# PowerShell If Statement Failure

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I need another set of eyes because I'm certain this is simple but it's kicking my butt right now. I'm writing a script to install Windows roles/features on both Server 2008 and Server 2012 machines.

I know that 2008 uses `Add-WindowsFeature` whereas 2012 uses `Install-WindowsFeature`.  So my goal is to look at the OS and if it's 2008 create a variable called `$Install` with a value of `Add-WindowsFeature` and if it's not 2008 give it the value of `Install-WindowsFeature`.

This is what I have now:

```
$OS = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).Name

if ($OS -like '2008') {
    $Install = 'Add-WindowsFeature'
} else {
    $Install = 'Install-WindowsFeature'
}
```

Currently, when I call up the `$OS` variable I get a returned value of:

```
Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard |C:\Windows|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition2
```

But when I call up the `$Install` variable I get a returned value of:

```
Install-WindowsFeature
```

I've also tried `-contains` instead of `-like` but I get the same result.  I've also tried eliminating the spaces before the curly brackets, but still no change.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding some wildcards to your pattern: `$OS -like '*2008*'`

Comment: Thanks.  I knew it had to be something stupid simple!

Comment: Also try `caption` property instead of `name`.

Comment: Also -contains would only match whole words in an array, while .contains() matches substrings, lol.  You could also use -match and not have to put wildcards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-like` operator is not a regular expression comparison. If you don't have any wildcards, the `-like` match is the same as an equality comparison.

You need to either include wildcards, like this:

```
if ($OS -like '*2008*') {
```

do a contains check, like this:

```
if ($OS.Contains('2008')) {
```

or use a regular expression match, like this:

```
if ($OS -match '2008') {
```

Documentation is here:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively the cmdlet `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature` should be available on 2008 and beyond machines. You should be able to use that to install whatever feature you need regardless of the OS.

Comment: Is there a module for that?  It's not liking the term Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature

Comment: It's in the DISM module. It should be with PS 3.0. I can't recall off the top of my head which PS came with which Windows.